# How to filter unflagged items in outlook using vba

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

While creating a macro which extracts some data from all unflagged messages in outlook. i am able to get the data by using loop and checking the status of each mail in inbox however the count of mails in inbox is huge. so is there a way to filter only unflagged item and then get the data from the filtered mails.

I tried the following code. However its not working for me.

```
Mailbox = Cells(k, 1).Value

Set Fldr = olNs.Folders(Mailbox).Folders("inbox")
Fldr.Items.Restrict ("followupflag:unflagged")
```

Is there a way with which i can speedup the macro.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Restrict("[FlagStatus] = 0")`. Keep in mind that Restrict returns a new instance of the Items collection.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model provides the following ways for getting a subset of items that correspond to your conditions:

1. The [Restrict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the Items class. See [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/) for more information.
2. The **Find/FindNext** methods of the Items class. See [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/) .
3. The **AdvancedSearch** method of the Application class. See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) . The key benefits of using the AdvancedSearch method in Outlook are:

   - The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the AdvancedSearch method runs it automatically in the background.
   - Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The Restrict and Find/FindNext methods can be applied to a particular Items collection (see the Items property of the Folder class in Outlook).
   - Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the Filtering article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the IsInstantSearchEnabled property of the Store class).
   - Finally, you can stop the search process at any moment using the Stop method of the Search class.

Finally, the sample code is included in the articles.